# WaitUntil RXJS operator

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I need to find a solution with rxjs operator. I'm working on an angular app with ngrx and I want to wait when a ngrx selector become populated.

I have an effects for notification, i call an sse service and I need to standby the pipe until the observable "Firm$" will return a not empty array. How can I solve this?

```
    loadEVents$ = createEffect(() =>
        this.actions$.pipe(
          ofType('[WebSocketNotification] Load WebSocketNotification'),
          mergeMap(() =>
            this.webSocketEventsService.getServerSentEvent(`${environment.SERVER_API_URL}/services/synbee-api-events/api/notification`).pipe(
              filter((notif: Notification) => notif.notificationType !== 'OK' && notif.seen === false),
              map(res => (this.notification = res)),
              switchMap(() => this.Firm$),
              WAITUNTIL(res => res.length > 0),
              map(()=> {
                if (this.notification.notificationType === 'SHARING') {
                  this.Firm$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(firms => {
                    if (firms.find(firm => firm.id === this.notification.idFirm) === undefined) {
                      this.serviceFirm.getFirms();
                    }
                  });
                }
                return { type: notificationActions.ActionNotificationType.LOAD_NOTIFICATION_SUCCESS, notification: this.notification };
              }),
              catchError(() => {
                return EMPTY;
              })
            )
          )
        )
      );
```

I tried with repeat and filter operators but it interrupts all the flux.

Answer (score 1):

To have something "wait" you need to introduce an asynchronous function and `await` it.  You can use a subscription and a `filter` to do this.

```js
async function getNonEmptyFirm() {
   return firstValueFrom(this.Firm$.pipe(
      filter(firm => firm.length > 0)
   ));
}
```

replace your

```js
switchMap(() => this.Firm$),
WAITUNTIL(res => res.length > 0),
```

with

```js
mergeMap(async notification => {
    const firm = await getNonEmptyFirm(); 
    return {notification, firm};
}),
```

You have lots of refactoring you could do to improve this, though.  Using `map` to store the notification is discouraged and is what `tap` is intended.  However you need `notification` later, so I would pass it along as well as the value you get from firm.  Then you can get rid of the `take(1).subscribe` and `this.notification` and keep everything self-contained.  The way you have it written with `this.notification` will lose earlier values and only have the latest one.  If you do not want that behavior read on.

With the above, I would do something like

```js
map(({notification, firm}) => {
    if (notification.notificationType === 'SHARING') {
        if (firm.find(f => f.id === notification.idFirm) === undefined) {
            this.serviceFirm.getFirms();
        }
    }
    return { type: notificationActions.ActionNotificationType.LOAD_NOTIFICATION_SUCCESS, notification };
})
```

If you still need to have a value for `this.notification` for anything outside that function use

```js
tap(res => {this.notification = res}),
```